# Substitution replaces only current line?

Tags: substitute, vim-windows

I have a block of of text which contains variables whose name I want to change, **but not all**. I want to be able to choose which variables get replaced by the substitution and which do not. I tried using `:%s/pattern/string/c`, but the problem with that is that it starts from the beginning of the file, which also has the variables which I don't want to replace.

From `:h :s`:

```
:[range]s[ubstitute]/{pattern}/{string}/[flags] [count]
                        For each line in [range] replace a match of {pattern}
                        with {string}.
                        For the {pattern} see |pattern|.
                        {string} can be a literal string, or something
                        special; see |sub-replace-special|.
                        When [range] and [count] are omitted, replace in the
                        current line only.  When [count] is given, replace in
                        [count] lines, starting with the last line in [range].
                        When [range] is omitted start in the current line.
```

Specifically:

```
When [count] is given, replace in count] lines, starting with the last line in [range].
When [range] is omitted start in the current line.
```

My plan was to run the substitution once, then repeat it using `&` as many times as needed.
However, if I do `:s/pattern/string 1`, unless the pattern exists in the current line, the substitution cannot find the pattern. I can only conclude I misunderstood the wording.

What is the best way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Using the `c` flag with a range doesn't work?  E.g. `20,100s/pattern/string/c` ....  Also, do you have `'gdefault'` set?

Comment: @BLayer It does, but I would want the process of defining the range. Just have the same functionality as that command starting from the current line onward. I don't have `gdefault` set.

Comment: If you don't have `'gdefault'` you should be using `g` flag, no? I'm not quite sure what you mean by "I would want the process of defining the range". The process?

Comment: @BLayer Sorry, that was a mistype on my end. I meant that I wanted to avoid range selection when doing this type of substitution. As far as I understand, the `g` flag controls if there should be only one substitution per line or more. In any case, both options don't work as I intend.

Comment: Yes, that's what `g` does. I guess you're implying that you don't need to replace more than one word per line.

Comment: Something like `n`-and-dot, I guess.

Comment: Does `:s/pattern/string 1/e` help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default range for `:substitute` is `.`, the current line.

The simplest way to run a substitute that cannot fail is to use the `e` flag.

If you want to instead substitute the first occurrence after the cursor, I suggest

```
:/pattern/substitute//replace/flags
```

Alternately, if you really can't use `:%substitute` and you want behavior like the `c` flag, try searching `/pattern`, using `cgn` to put in the replacement, and then using `n` to navigate and `.` to repeat the change. (This is nice because, if you already know the next occurrence needs changed, you can skip the `n` and just press `.`.)

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I wanted. Playing around, I also notice it was possible to substitute the first line, then use `n` which finds the next pattern, and repeating the substitution for the line using `&`, but your alternative method is much quicker and intuitive.